# Can an indoor Birds of Paradise thrive in gardening soil?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, soil, repotting

I bought [gardening soil](https://www.miraclegro.com/en-us/products/soils/miracle-gro-all-purpose-garden-soil) by accident and I have a beautiful and large BoP that I'm repotting. I am curious if gardening soil will be OK for this plant.